# frame size beamer

Tags: beamer, margins, columns

I am using beamer to create a simple presentation. I want to be able to set the width and height of all frames with respect to the slide size?
Then I also would like to change the margin between columns, so that I make use of space more efficiently.

working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amssymb,amstext,amsmath,latexsym,mathtools}
\usepackage[italian,british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose}
\usepackage{movie15}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{abc}
abc
\begin{columns}[c]
\column{1.2in}
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig.pdf}}\\
abc\\
\column{1.2in}
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig.pdf}}\\
abc\\
\column{1.2in}
abc\\
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use fractions of `\linewidth` to fix the width of your columns. ex: `\column{.3\linewidth}` for each of three columns. The margins between the columns share the rest (`.1\linewidth`).

Comment: Thank you very much. This works well, but the margins of the slide itself is not fixed, so e.g. I get the last image to the right incomplete while there is space in the left margin unused!

Comment: so use fractions of `\paperwidth` to fix the width of your columns...

Comment: thank you very much. very good although I do not get equal margins in right and left. Aren't there specific slide margins set by default?

Comment: @Paul it seems that your comments answer at least most of the question.  Please consider converting them into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use fractions of `\linewidth` to fix the width of your columns. ex: `\column{.3\linewidth}` for each of three columns. The margins between the columns share the rest (`.1\linewidth`). If the margins of the slide itself are not fixed, use fractions of `\paperwidth` to fix the width of your columns.